# Python and Selenium - Unable to check checkbox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Im trying to check/uncheck a checkbox using Selenium and the click function. But no mather what I try it wont check it. One thing thats strange is that when I inspect the HTML in Chrome it has one ID but if I view source, same checkbox has another ID.

Inspect html code:

```
<div class="checkbox-inline col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 m-l-sm rightCheckBox">
            <div class="icheckbox_square-blue" style="position: relative;"><input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" name="PanelsContainer:tabsContentView:2:listTabs:rights-group-container:right-type-view:2:right-view:2:affected-right" id="ida1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins></div> <label>Delete group</label>
</div>
```

View soruce html:

```
    <div class="checkbox-inline col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 m-l-sm rightCheckBox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" name="PanelsContainer:tabsContentView:6:listTabs:rights-group-container:right-type-view:2:right-view:2:affected-right" id="id14e"> <label>Delete group</label>
    </div><div class="checkbox-inline col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 m-l-sm rightCheckBox">
```

Im 100% sure its the same checkbox. When I try using the ID from the view source code it doesnt find anything, but when I use the Inspect html code ID the code completes but the checkbox doesnt get checked.

I have tested alot of different methods, but no luck.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=ida1')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()

driver.find_element_by_id('ida1').click()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=ida1')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Edited:

I have allso tried using this code to find the ID and then use that value for the code above.

```
        find_id = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@name="PanelsContainer:tabsContentView:2:listTabs:rights-group-container:right-type-view:2:right-view:2:affected-right"]')
        for my_id in find_id:
            delete_id = my_id.get_attribute("id")
```

When using that I allways get an ID, but if I change **tabsContentView:2** to **tabsContentView:6** (difference between using inspect html code vs view-source html code) it doesnt find any ID or anything els.

Answer (score 0):

Try text of attched label and then use preceding-sibling method. Use below xpath to identify your checkbox.

```
//label[text()='Delete group']//preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']
```

Comment: Thanks, but getting this error when using that code: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
Code I used is: 
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[text()="Delete group"]//preceding-sibling::input[@type="checkbox"]').click()
Allso, theres 4 instences of "Delete group" in the HTML code, Im trying to check the second one.

Comment: You are using find_element**s** instead of find_element.

Comment: To click second , if there is no other attribute which you can use to differentiate ( I can’t tell as you have shared HTML for only one ), you can use index as below : driver.find_element_by_xpath(“(//label[text()='Delete group']//preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox'])[2]”).click()